# Computing digits of number in another base

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to program a procedure to convert a number in base 10 to a set of digits in an arbitrary base.

Through empirical testing I see that the procedure involves repeated mod operations and div operations to give the digits in least significant order.
i.e.

```
// Returns list of NUMBER's (>=0) digits in BASE (>=2) in least
// significant to most significant order.

function convertToBase(number, base):
    digits = list()
    while number != 0:
        add (number mod base) to digits
        let number := number / base
    return digits
```

But I have **little intuition** for why this procedure works? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how it works for a real example, say when `number=125` in decimal.

First `digits=list()`. Then it adds `125 mod 10` to that, so `digits=(5)` now, then we perform integer division `125 / 10` that results in `number=12`.

In the next round, as `12 mod 10=2`, we will have `digits=(5,2)` (if `add` adds it to the right) and `number=12/10=1`.

Finally, we end up with `digits=(5,2,1)`, and as the integer division of `1/10` results in `0`, the procedure will end.

The same goes on with every other number system.

Comment: yes I completely understand that. But my question is why does is the algorithm *mathematically* correct (intuitively, perhaps)?